# call stored procedure from java springboot program pool empty error

Tags: java

I have a springboot application which calls a stored procedure quite frequently which performs some inserts and update to some of tables. I can see that functionally this code works but after a while I can more number of connections are open and any new request to run any query is not being satisified and getting below error

```
'Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000].","logger_name":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper"'
```

Below is code which invokes the stored procedure,  I tried changing to a different implementation using entity manager as well but same result

Will appreciate any thoughts on the issue , also let me know if anything is not mentioned.

```
@Transactional
private Status bulkSaveOrderInterfaceStatus(String procName,String orderIds,  
  interfaceType, String errorMsg, String status) {

    String outPutPram;
    try(Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate()) {
        SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) session.getSessionFactory();
        Session ses = sessionFactory.openSession();
        ses.beginTransaction();
        ProcedureCall storedProcedure =  ses.createStoredProcedureCall(procName);
        storedProcedure.registerParameter(SqlConstants.BULK_INS_PROCEDURE_ORDERID_INPUTPARM, String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(orderIds);
        storedProcedure.registerParameter(SqlConstants.BULK_INS_PROCEDURE_INTERFACETYPE_INPUTPARM,String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(interfaceType);
        storedProcedure.registerParameter(SqlConstants.BULK_INS_PROCEDURE_ERRORMSG_INPUTPARM,String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(errorMsg);
        storedProcedure.registerParameter(SqlConstants.BULK_INS_PROCEDURE_STATUS_INPUTPARM,String.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(status);
        storedProcedure.registerParameter(SqlConstants.PROCEDURE_OUTPUT_MESSAGE, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        outPutPram = (String) storedProcedure.getOutputs().getOutputParameterValue(SqlConstants.PROCEDURE_OUTPUT_MESSAGE);
        ses.getTransaction().commit();
        if (outPutPram.equals(SqlConstants.PROCEDURE_STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
            return Status.SUCCESS;
        } else {
            return Status.ERROR;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Status.ERROR;
    } 

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your data-source property file or Hibernate property file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should close session and it is better to do it in finally or use try with resource statement.

```
 finally {
     ses.close(); 
  }
```

Comment: that 's right ;) i didn't notice he use try and resource statement.

Comment: sorry i missed here. I even tried using it in a finally block but still same issue

Comment: Do you close ses reference in finally ?